# MySQL: How to refer to an item already mentioned in a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

On a self-learn website, I used a SQLlite interface that allowed me to refer to an item that I just wrote.

Ex.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) AS **Name**, CONCAT(**Name**, ' ', ID) 
FROM Players;
```

I tried doing that on MySQL (in case if it matters, I'm using the Cloud9 platform) and it doesn't work. Should it work and I'm simply not doing it right? Or there is no such thing?

Comment: Did you really put `**` around the `Name`? You can't do highlighting in code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not work.  SQL (in general) does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  Hence, it doesn't allow re-use of aliases defined in the same level.

In your case, the simplest solution is to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) AS Name, CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName, ' ', ID)
FROM Players;
```

Not elegant, but it gets the job done.

In MySQL, this is better than a subquery, because MySQL materializes subqueries, adding additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.Name, ' ', A.ID) FROM
(
    SELECT ID, CONCAT(fName, ' ', lName) AS Name FROM PLAYERS A
) A
```

However, from a performance perspective, you are better off with the original query I think even if its longer.